# Jquery ajax, $.each wait to finish

Tags: ajax

I've been looking for the last couples days for a good solution for this problem. but can't seem to find one.

I have a Jquery script that has to loop through each element get a value and then do an Ajax call, however this is thousands of elements so i would like for the script to go element by element and only move to the next one once the previous action has finished, i tried asyc but that does not seem to wait properly and causes the page to freeze and miss a lot of elements and cause errors.

what advise/script would you suggest i try or look into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, but it's probably very specific, since i have unique ID's for each element what i did was:

first i defined an empty array and a variable for counting

on the initial click for each loop placing each SKU in an array, once done execute the ajax function

ajax function get's the index of current count then executes function

then i +1 the count and if it is less than the length of the array call ajax function again

i tried to explain it as open as possible in case someone has the same sort of situation, but you can always find a way to assign a random value to your element to somehow identify it